# ERCOT API: Send SOAP XML with signature and Binary security token using Python

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

I have the following code which is used to post data to a SOAP server . I have used the zeep module but getting error. does zeep module support https calls?-
the error is coming while executing the ssl.py, adapter.py.etc.
can we create request without zeep and apply the binary signature some other way?

````
import os
from zeep import Client, Settings
from zeep.transports import Transport
from requests import Session
from requests_pkcs12 import Pkcs12Adapter
from zeep.wsse.signature import BinarySignature
import random
import logging.config
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding, PrivateFormat, NoEncryption
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12 import load_key_and_certificates

# USE THE MOST VERBOSE LOGGING LEVEL
logging.config.dictConfig({
 'version': 1,
 'formatters': {
 'verbose': {
 'format': '%(name)s: %(message)s'
 }
 },
 'handlers': {
 'console': {
 'level': 'DEBUG',
 'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
 'formatter': 'verbose',
 },
 },
 'loggers': {
 'zeep.transports': {
 'level': 'DEBUG',
 'propagate': True,
 'handlers': ['console'],
 },
 }
})


# Source: https://gist.github.com/erikbern/756b1d8df2d1487497d29b90e81f8068
@contextlib.contextmanager
def pfx_to_pem(pfx_path, pfx_password):
 ''' Decrypts the .pfx file to be used with requests. '''
 pfx = Path(pfx_path).read_bytes()
 private_key, main_cert, add_certs = load_key_and_certificates(pfx, pfx_password.encode('utf-8'), None)

 with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pem', delete=False) as t_pem:
   with open(t_pem.name, 'wb') as pem_file:
     pem_file.write(private_key.private_bytes(Encoding.PEM, PrivateFormat.PKCS8, NoEncryption()))
     pem_file.write(main_cert.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM))
     for ca in add_certs:
       pem_file.write(ca.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM))
   yield t_pem.name


def generate_nonce(length=15):
 """Generate pseudorandom number."""
 return ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(length)])


# CERTIFICATES PATHS
api_pfx_key = os.path.join('C:\\ALL\\ERCOT\\API Outplan OSI TCC MOTE.pfx')
api_certificate = os.path.join('C:\\ALL\\ERCOT\\OSITCC.cer')

# SETUP
wsdl_file = os.path.join('C:\\ALL\\ERCOT\\Nodal.wsdl')

#wsdl_file = "https://testmisapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS/?WSDL"
api_base_url = "https://testmisapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS/"
session = Session()
session.mount(api_base_url,
 Pkcs12Adapter(pkcs12_filename=api_pfx_key, pkcs12_password='AEP'))
#session.verify = False

transport = Transport(session=session)
settings = Settings(forbid_entities=False)

# CREATE CLIENT
print("Creating client.")
with pfx_to_pem(pfx_path=api_pfx_key, pfx_password='AEP') as pem_fle:
 client = Client(wsdl_file, settings=settings, transport=transport,
 wsse=BinarySignature(pem_fle, api_certificate))

 print("Making request.")
 request_data = {
 "Header": {
 "Verb": "get",
 "Noun": "SystemStatus",
 "ReplayDetection": {
 "Nonce": generate_nonce(),
 "Created": "07-06-2022"},
 "Revision": "1",
 "Source": "TDSP",
 "UserID": "API_OutplanOSITCC",
 },
 }
 print("Call URL")
 print(client.service.MarketTransactions(**request_data))```


but while running this one , I am getting the below error - "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\python.exe" "C:/ALL/Python 3.10/PythonDev/ERCOT_API.py"
C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py:1133: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: This version of cryptography contains a temporary pyOpenSSL fallback path. Upgrade pyOpenSSL now.
  cert._x509 = crypto_cert._x509
Creating client.
zeep.transports: Loading remote data from: http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd
Making request.
Call URL
zeep.transports: HTTP Post to https://testmisapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#id-c773cb6e-3a71-4d59-8a83-e3e4df97cd03">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>jhEnAC9hpCVo1d/0+2Gj7bO2IzE=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>XhJV0FuRemJRlgwGoLLo13cR+vjtUartO2eyIj9rjQoOVR4NES3ULki26wCrF5nT
ABAFjdh7nr9BQry4L+ZcnQt2T73SMsFBUaSWFhp2jEuHIPdnHhnkRqNMJt+p+cPS
cXojjDlvjmqB9uEF5wk/dEQIfWdp0aE5tlnV7qRJUh7Mm43k43vVCOW+Sn3i3k7a
7Td74UukP7XsENL0x804DAEmYI686gWNCBzSyNojNWcT/1SKa+gaM1mqe9KPOzpq
dFOUOYLyEDqeYJdUTwTzBGHatuWX536fFcl7AOp9aBYCtFCwyoQ5cweSdZdATd47
Hp/TtICaKb8Xg2XZ/c3wHA==</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference><wsse:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#id-6a68c676-049c-4dc8-9f59-9dcb6a173bb0"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo>
</Signature><wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ns1:Id="id-6a68c676-049c-4dc8-9f59-9dcb6a173bb0">MIIGXDCCBUSgAwIBAgIQOQpxxst8nF94i/e9RtEgCzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBm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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:Security></soap-env:Header><soap-env:Body xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" ns1:Id="id-c773cb6e-3a71-4d59-8a83-e3e4df97cd03"><ns0:RequestMessage xmlns:ns0="http://www.ercot.com/schema/2007-06/nodal/ews/message"><ns0:Header><ns0:Verb>get</ns0:Verb><ns0:Noun>SystemStatus</ns0:Noun><ns0:ReplayDetection><ns0:Nonce>576394325909862</ns0:Nonce><ns0:Created>07-06-2022</ns0:Created></ns0:ReplayDetection><ns0:Revision>1</ns0:Revision><ns0:Source>TDSP</ns0:Source><ns0:UserID>API_OutplanOSITCC</ns0:UserID></ns0:Header></ns0:RequestMessage></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\ssl.py", line 501, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\ssl.py", line 1041, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\ssl.py", line 1310, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='testmisapi.ercot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1129)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.10\PythonDev\ERCOT_API.py", line 98, in <module>
    print(client.service.MarketTransactions(**request_data))
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\zeep\proxy.py", line 46, in __call__
    return self._proxy._binding.send(
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 127, in send
    response = client.transport.post_xml(options["address"], envelope, http_headers)
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\zeep\transports.py", line 107, in post_xml
    return self.post(address, message, headers)
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\zeep\transports.py", line 73, in post
    response = self.session.post(
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 635, in post
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ALL\Python 3.9\PythonDev\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='testmisapi.ercot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1129)')))

Process finished with exit code 1

Could anyone please suggest how to resolve this error?

Thank you so much for your time and help.
@Anna Geller ,@Preethi Vaidyanathan -could you please help with this?

Thanks
Sugata
````

Comment: "does zeep module support https calls?" yes, of course. The error is not related to support or not of TLS, it is related to some problem with the certificate received. Did you try to download that specific URL you use with another client and see what happens at the TLS layer? In my browser, I get same error, hence strongly hitting about a problem at the server side, not in your client code. Did you see the warning also about upgrading PyOpenSSL?

Comment: Thank you @PatrickMevzek for your response. I was able to find the error. I changed the file extension for the pfx to p12 when using it for the pkcs adapter. 
Now I am having trouble with the XML formatting. My code is generating the signed XML in a different way that is expected by the partner.Not sure, if that will cause any issue while posting the data. I'll add that here.
Thanks
Sugata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer: Just tried to update and requested help on this-
Edited Version after changing the code:
I have fixed the issue for SSL,I am now able to connect and get the response. But, the SOAP XML is generated in a different way than it is expected by the partner.
Below XML is expected by partner-

```
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-B526F1951BD81739D3166098806721395">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature Id="SIG-B526F1951BD81739D3166098806721599" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soapenv wsu" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-B526F1951BD81739D3166098806721398"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsu" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>kVIVovzVfbEzUdlGbrk9sDvKf6A=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>f4Ds96E3rsWfUu7+LxATRZJ2jCOWTkdzg9pySOuAoHfwl0o1/uhNo/KMGxtYZHX0pwbPw5Hhl0wa0m+4yX4BJybnyfMATWfHL8xER8XLUqXFdu4Gxg/3vQt9m5Es3Tt9lkchbTk1DXnFtm6dVryrpcgD0SZ6hktA33HrBuW5rvTir1AEgAN+lfsjXpcxc5pXAXoIBDcoiM8FVr8M6Sc7BzcIRImkRG3HGlBNbc0MTBINDr9gAd+VeEkj65DSRhJbsDkMmeIoBjhcxAG0DXrFfXgeFGqPGJV+MUCsgIQ3QX7pI1oz5ydCQnaTIlEGX+RWcJHnxEGK7Ip2Cxfw+9UrXg==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-B526F1951BD81739D3166098806721396"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-B526F1951BD81739D3166098806721397"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-B526F1951BD81739D3166098806721395" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-B526F1951BD81739D3166098806721398" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <RequestMessage xmlns="http://www.ercot.com/schema/2007-06/nodal/ews/message">
         <Header>
            <Verb>get</Verb>
            <Noun>SystemStatus</Noun>
            <ReplayDetection>
               <Nonce>9938998019</Nonce>
               <Created>2022-08-20T03:23:00-06:00</Created>
            </ReplayDetection>
            <Revision>004</Revision>
            <Source>API Outplan OSI TCC</Source>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <UserID>API_OutplanOSITCC</UserID>
            
         </Header>
 
      </RequestMessage>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

XML generated by my code -

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#id-9d18c15b-7ea9-47f0-b1c5-d7e1092ba7e2">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>Qfdgh1Pl7BEYpLkQkgwiqq+2bMQ=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>m/kqFxxOW4oeSBtHIcfJePo1d0vupLhDC04Ju2u6cB3TP3RbGc6Q+R1r5cokVu6V
fnT2p5e6/bbb1ekl+Xw/e9AByb82YqesUDibhXTDw47jjtN7q+sJotLKD0CzL+4Z
IVsizpOASoFBj6BaB+Fkdk6pw8cC+1ZwQtpQIR9J4bLUSRMHWU3dr7sBRt7Rb7Nb
f1L/5CtiMXi+jtfQvmmdw5kHX76a3USVMBynH8BJR+HFwpabDa00tVjfPMm/mWUa
XFnTjRKVFs4LjA6xgYH6PE6kO37spqiss+w9bSYuv4oMLslD6fOTkd1geVtXWOar
iqeDb6Z8qKvpE4gEAjN9HQ==</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#id-b9a43d44-6015-419b-8e84-87a537c4cb7a"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ns1:Id="id-b9a43d44-6015-419b-8e84-87a537c4cb7a">MIIGXDCCBUSgAwIBAgIQOQpxxst8nF94i/e9RtEgCzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBm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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" ns1:Id="id-9d18c15b-7ea9-47f0-b1c5-d7e1092ba7e2">
        <ns0:RequestMessage xmlns:ns0="http://www.ercot.com/schema/2007-06/nodal/ews/message">
            <ns0:Header>
                <ns0:Verb>get</ns0:Verb>
                <ns0:Noun>SystemStatus</ns0:Noun>
                <ns0:ReplayDetection>
                    <ns0:Nonce>751702826976894</ns0:Nonce>
                    <ns0:Created>2022-08-29T21:30:00-06:00</ns0:Created>
                </ns0:ReplayDetection>
                <ns0:Revision>1</ns0:Revision>
                <ns0:Source>API Outplan OSI TCC</ns0:Source>
                <ns0:UserID>API_OutplanOSITCC</ns0:UserID>
            </ns0:Header>
        </ns0:RequestMessage>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hello Everyone,
Could you anyone please help with this?

Comment: I was able to resolve this by changing the wsdl location they provided. Changed to this -https://testmisapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS/
no needed to add any ns prefixes. It worked with the same code.

Comment: here is the detailed analysis and modified / clean code-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73738245/python-xmlsec-verificationerror-signature-is-invalid-error-even-after-receivi/73739097#73739097